# Getting ERROR DOMAIN- 3840 while uploading a image

Tags: ios, swift, api

Error 3480 in API post request for a image upload to server with json parse API call.

> Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "No value." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=No value.}

```
func updateImageApiCall() {

    self.userApi.editImage(userId:UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "UserID") as! String, profilePhoto: userImageUrl!, completion:{(response, error) in
       let data = response?.data(using: .utf8)!
    do {
        let jsonObj = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments) as! [String: Any]

        if jsonObj["error"] as! Bool == false {
              let data = self.imageOfUser
              UserDefaults.standard.set(data, forKey: "userImage")
              Global.sharedInstance.saveImageDocumentDirectory(data!)

              self.hideLoader()
              self.showLoader(withMsg: "fetching information...")
              self.getUserApiCall()
         }

    } catch {
        print("error->\(error)")
    }
 })
}
```

When I call this function the error is shown and this API does not runs in my device.

I had tried to convert the URL to string and tried some calling of this function in other flow but it docent work.

It is post API request for uploading a image of a profile I am getting error in this call.

When I am getting response as false then I can run the further code for the API to call its result, this is the code below for API call post request with only JSON parse .

Comment: show your editImage function code

Comment: if let pickedImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage] as? UIImage {userImage.contentMode = .scaleToFill
 userImage.image = pickedImage
 var data: NSData!
 if imageName.suffix(3) == "png" || imageName.suffix(3) == "PNG" {
data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(pickedImage)! as NSData
  print("profiledata1/\(String(describing: data))")
            } else {
  data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(pickedImage, 1)! as NSData  }
 imageOfUser = UIImagePNGRepresentation(pickedImage)
 data.write(toFile: localPath, atomically: true)
 userImageUrl = URL.init(fileURLWithPath: localPath)
        }

Comment: above code is after  image taken from gallery or camera @Scriptable